# How can I add a list element on initialization

Tags: c#, model, initialization

I have a simple question on initialization of a list-property inside a model.
My model:

```
class FileToWrite
{
    public FileToWrite()
    {
        Filename = string.Empty;
        FileType = ExportFileType.IGNORE;
        InputVar = string.Empty;
        Var = string.Empty;
        InOutVar = string.Empty;
        OutputVar = string.Empty;
        Header = string.Empty;
        Footer = string.Empty;
        Bodies = new List<string>();
        Overwrite = Overwrite.FALSE;
    }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public ExportFileType FileType { get; set; }
    public string InputVar { get; set; }
    public string Var { get; set; }
    public string InOutVar { get; set; }
    public string OutputVar { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public List<string> Bodies { get; set; }
    public string Footer { get; set; }
    public Overwrite Overwrite { get; set; }

}
```

Actually, I initialize it as follows:

```
FileToWrite fileToWrite = new FileToWrite()
{
    FileType = fileType
};
fileToWrite.Bodies.Add(string.Empty);
```

Is there a way to do it like this:

```
FileToWrite fileToWrite = new FileToWrite()
{
    FileType = fileType,
    Bodies.Add(string.Empty)
};
```

I think technically it makes no difference but looks smarter.

Thanks Carsten

Comment: You want to add an empty string to `Bodies` on initialization ?

Comment: Disregarding your motives here, `FileType = fileType, Bodies = new List<string>() {string.EmptyString}`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all...
As I only need the empty string in some cases, this is the best solution.

To insert that into the constructor would solve this issue but would cause troubles on other scenarios in my program.

```
FileToWrite fileToWrite = new FileToWrite()
{
    FileType = fileType,
    Bodies = new List<string>() { string.Empty };
};
```

works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>()
{
   "Hello",
   "Answer",
   "Hello"
}

Foreach (string item in stringList)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output :

> Hello
>
> Answer
>
> Hello

EDIT : Exactly your Case

You can add the Line on Init of the List itself not the object :

```
public FileToWrite()
    {
        Filename = string.Empty;
        FileType = ExportFileType.IGNORE;
        InputVar = string.Empty;
        Var = string.Empty;
        InOutVar = string.Empty;
        OutputVar = string.Empty;
        Header = string.Empty;
        Footer = string.Empty;
        Bodies = new List<string>()
        {
          ""
        }
        Overwrite = Overwrite.FALSE;
    }
```

But to your Question, no its not possible to do that, not with bodies.add()

possible solutions would be :

Make a parameter in Constructor of the Object (with/without empty string) and when constructor is called :

```
public FileToWrite(bool DoEmpty = false)
{        
    if (DoEmpty)
    {
        bodies.add("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an empty string to bodies collection every single time, then you can do the following in the constructor. This will add an empty string automatically when the object gets initialized.

```
class FileToWrite
{
    public FileToWrite()
    {
        Filename = string.Empty;
        FileType = ExportFileType.IGNORE;
        InputVar = string.Empty;
        Var = string.Empty;
        InOutVar = string.Empty;
        OutputVar = string.Empty;
        Header = string.Empty;
        Footer = string.Empty;
        Bodies = new List<string>() { string.Empty };
        Overwrite = Overwrite.FALSE;
    }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public ExportFileType FileType { get; set; }
    public string InputVar { get; set; }
    public string Var { get; set; }
    public string InOutVar { get; set; }
    public string OutputVar { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public List<string> Bodies { get; set; }
    public string Footer { get; set; }
    public Overwrite Overwrite { get; set; }

}
```